# Read specific text from current url and assign to a text box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to get the name from current url and assign it to a text box.

```
http://www.myabc.com/123/kdkd?refid=hari-doss
```

I just want to display "hari-doss" from the above url in a text box.

Note that the name is dynamic one. It will change depends on the user account.

Could anyone please help me out.

Comment: there is nothing under url

Comment: `var arr = window.location.href.split(/\/+/); var name = arr[4]||''`

Comment: USe window.location.href.split("/").pop()

Comment: And suddenly, the requirement changed.

Comment: I am sorry for this changes... This is the correct format of url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a function that I have been using for the past couple of years -

```
function getQueryStringValue(key) {
    key = key.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + key + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Here is the usage -

```
$('#textbox').html(getQueryStringValue(refid));
```

This allows you to return the value of any key in a query string and also allows for changes to the query string (more values, etc.)

Comment: I tried this code, but, I didn't get any output. How do I need to implement this one.

Comment: You call getQueryStringValue(key goes here) with the key in the query string that you want to return.

Answer (score 1):

the following script will give you the name.there is a function for extract query string at url

```
var QueryString = function () {
            // This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and
            // the return value is assigned to QueryString!
            var query_string = {};
            var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var vars = query.split("&");
            for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
                var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                // If first entry with this name
                if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
                    query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];
                    // If second entry with this name
                } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
                    var arr = [query_string[pair[0]], pair[1]];
                    query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
                    // If third or later entry with this name
                } else {
                    query_string[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);
                }
            }
            return query_string;
        }(); 

     var name = QueryString.refid;
```

Comment: I have changed the question. This is the correct format of url. I am sorry for this changes...

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/username_here801";
var urlsplit = url.split("/");
var username = urlsplit[3];
$('#textboxid').val(username);
```

Comment: I have changed the question. This is the correct format of url. I am sorry for this changes...

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
//for getting current page URL
//var current_url = document.URL;
//so considering the current page URL = http://www.myabc.com/123/kdkd?refid=hari-doss
var current_url = "http://www.myabc.com/123/kdkd?refid=hari-doss";
var pos = current_url.lastIndexOf("=");
var name = current_url.substring(pos+1, current_url.length); 
alert(name);//with output "hari-doss"
```

Comment: I have changed the question. This is the correct format of url. I am sorry for this changes... –  user3775881 1 min ago   edit

Comment: updated my code in my answer. Try this !

Comment: How can i load this alert variable into the input box. I tried using document.getElementById("parentuserid").innerHTML = name;. But it is not working.

Comment: What happens if other things are added to the query string?

Comment: @RahulGupta,Thanks for the code. It works fine.

Comment: @RahulGupta. It works fine as long as there is something after equal to(=). If nothing is there after that it simply displays full url in the result. I don't want to display full url. How can I do that.